# Menu keeps hiding when hovering over menu links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a website http://www.jordanswebsite.3eeweb.com. (I know it's bread, it's a project I have to do and I choose bread). And on the left I have my navigation. My problem is, when you hover the div, it comes out as it's suppose to. But if you hover over the links it disappears. here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="side_bar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="//jordanswebsite.3eeweb.com/index.php"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//jordanswebsite.3eeweb.com/about/index.php"> About </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//jordanswebsite.3eeweb.com/history/index.php"> History </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="//jordanswebsite.3eeweb.com/facts/index.php"> Facts </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

SCSS:

```
div#side_bar {
    position: fixed; left: -12%; top: 0;
    width: 15%; height: 100%;
    background: rgb(220, 221, 222);
    z-index: 99999;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px 10px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.5);
    overflow: hidden;

    ul {
        position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: auto;
        padding: 0 0;

        li {
            width: 100%; height: 5%;
            display: block;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 4em;
            padding: 6% 2%;
            text-align: center;
            z-index: 9;
            position: relative; right: 5px;

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("div#side_bar").bind({
        mouseenter: function(event) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: "0%"
            }, 300);
        },
        mouseout: function(event) {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                left: "-12%"
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I apologize if the menu doesn't show up well on your screen, I haven't optimized it for all screens yet.

Comment: jQuery is not included (only jquery-ui), add the link please - you'll get an error in moment.

Comment: **Link throws a malware warning in my anti-virus software**

Comment: Add your html and css directly to SO.

Comment: @Phoenix There ya go.